# Filter users post with user params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on an application and I try to implement a filter with filterrific on the post index.

The filter sort the post with user params : `mother_tongue`, `locality`, and `availability`.

- I CreateJoinTableUsersPosts
- Post belongs_to :user
- User has_one :post

Post.rb :

```
filterrific(
default_filter_params: {},
available_filters: [
  :with_mother_tongue,
  :with_locality,
  :with_start_time_gte
]
)

scope :with_mother_tongue, -> (search_string) { joins(:users).where("users.mother_tongue LIKE ?", (search_string.to_s.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%'))
}

scope :with_locality, -> (search_string) { joins(:users).where("users.locality LIKE ?", (search_string.to_s.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%'))
}

scope :with_start_time_gte, -> (ref_date) { joins(:availabilities).where('availabilities.start_time >= ?', ref_date) }
```

The filter works on users index but not on posts index with the error :

> Can't join 'Post' to association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled
>   it?

Do you know why there is this error ?

Comment: This is a bit wierd to me, you create `JoinTableUsersPosts` and have `Post belongs_to :user` and `User has_one :post`, the two options are sort of exclusive to each other.

Comment: it is supposed to be many to many relationship. accordingly you have to change the associations

Comment: Users can create only one post, How can I create an association between users and posts to exploit users_params on posts index ?

Comment: I think you already have `@user` defined in `ApplicationController`. BTW are you using devise?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the join table between users and posts, drop it. And your join should start working.
Other than that, if you are using devise gem, you already have `@user` available in all controllers inherting from `ApplicationController`. If not, then it's a whole different story. Research that, there are plenty of resources on that topic. 
Don't hesitate to comment, though.

Comment: I Drop the join table but I have a new error, @seethrough see my post upstairs. I don't use devise ! :/